# Utils.Scala Databricks ~ Twitter Stream in Scala

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark, streaming

I am working in IntelliJ and get this error:

```
Error:(118, 13) not found: value Utils
        Utils.parseCommandLineWithTwitterCredentials(args)
        ^
```

[This](https://github.com/databricks/reference-apps/blob/master/twitter_classifier/scala/src/main/scala/com/databricks/apps/twitter_classifier/Utils.scala) is the code is trying to reference.

The error resolves if I put this code directly into my main.

---

Here is my build.sbt file :

```
name := "TwtrStream"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.10" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.3.1"
```

---

Here is the code where I get my error : Utils.IntParam DOES NOT RESOLVE

```
object Collect {
    private var numTweetsCollected = 0L
    private var partNum = 0
    private var gson = new Gson()

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      // Process program arguments and set properties
      if (args.length < 3) {
        System.err.println("Usage: " + this.getClass.getSimpleName +
          "<outputDirectory> <numTweetsToCollect> <intervalInSeconds> <partitionsEachInterval>")
        System.exit(1)
      }
      val Array(outputDirectory, Utils.IntParam(numTweetsToCollect),  Utils.IntParam(intervalSecs), Utils.IntParam(partitionsEachInterval)) =
        Utils.parseCommandLineWithTwitterCredentials(args)
      /*
      https://github.com/databricks/reference-apps/blob/master/twitter_classifier/scala/src/main/scala/com/databricks/apps/twitter_classifier/Utils.scala
       */
      val outputDir = new File(outputDirectory.toString)
      if (outputDir.exists()) {
        System.err.println("ERROR - %s already exists: delete or specify another directory".format(
          outputDirectory))
        System.exit(1)
      }
      outputDir.mkdirs()

      println("Initializing Streaming Spark Context...")
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(this.getClass.getSimpleName)
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(intervalSecs))

      val tweetStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Utils.getAuth)
        .map(gson.toJson(_))

      tweetStream.foreachRDD((rdd, time) => {
        val count = rdd.count()
        if (count > 0) {
          val outputRDD = rdd.repartition(partitionsEachInterval)
          outputRDD.saveAsTextFile(outputDirectory + "/tweets_" + time.milliseconds.toString)
          numTweetsCollected += count
          if (numTweetsCollected > numTweetsToCollect) {
            System.exit(0)
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue is that you are trying to access a class that is not in your project nor in any of the libraries from your dependencies list.

So you'll need to add that class to your project or create a similar one.

```
your.package
|_ Collect.scala
|_ Utils.scala
```

Now you can use it in your Collect object code.